# Sysmon Configurations

Tags: security, logging, events, configuration

I have to work with windows event viewer where i was first required to install sysmon. As part of my first task, i am required to make sure that event id 11 and 22 work as they should. For event id 11(where it logs if a file has been created), it doesnt log whenever i create a file. For event id 22, i can see the logs but i cannot see the website that im accessing in the details tab. I was tasked to use the xml file sysmonconfig-export and configure it to make sure that the event id's display as they shoould. which line in the xms file do i change to make sure both id's work as i want them to?

my lecturer showed us how to make sure the event viewer showed event id 23 which was by changing the lines

```
<ClipboardChange onmatch="include">
        </ClipboardChange>
```

to

```
<FileDelete onmatch="exclude">
        </FileDelete>
```

which worked. but i have no idea how to work with event id's 11 and 22.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read Microsoft's documentation about Sysmon events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon#events)

You can also print Sysmon's schema by running the command `sysmon -s` (or `sysmon64 -s` for 64-bit), for example - Event ID 11:

```
<event name="SYSMONEVENT_FILE_CREATE" value="11" level="Informational" template="File created" rulename="FileCreate" ruledefault="exclude" version="2">
  <data name="RuleName" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
  <data name="UtcTime" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
  <data name="ProcessGuid" inType="win:GUID" />
  <data name="ProcessId" inType="win:UInt32" outType="win:PID" />
  <data name="Image" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
  <data name="TargetFilename" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
  <data name="CreationUtcTime" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
  <data name="User" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string" />
</event>
```